# Rooting my device, i can root it from the ROM?

Tags: rooting, samsung-galaxy-gio

i have a Samsung S5660 that i have upgraded to Android 2.3.7 but none of the previous hack or utilities seems to work with this version of Gingerbread.

I need it to be upgraded and rooted, i was thinking if it's possible to hack the ROM directly since i have a tar.md5 package with the ROM itself, because i have already tried everything, even something with `adb shell` directly into the phone but apparently nothing works.

How to root my phone ?

Comment: Have you considered using an alternate ROM like CyanogenMod or MIUI? Most alternate ROMs come pre-rooted. take a look at http://androidadvices.com/info/samsung/galaxy-gio-s5660/

Comment: @Sparx yes but they offer really poor performance if compared to the OEM provided ROM, also they are not reliable when it comes to testing and developing purposes. As you said, since most of them are pre-rooted i was looking for ideas about how to do this with my original ROM image.

Comment: XDA has a method to root while on stock ROM - http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=20397899&postcount=2  What previous hacks/utilities have you tried?

Comment: @Sparx gingerbreak and gingerbreak.apk, superuser.apk, psneuter, oneClickRoot, etc etc, and basically all the other ones, but i would like to know how to root a generic ROM so i can easily achieve this. I already have tried that method but doesn't look like it's really rooted, most of the tools under android doesn't look like being executed with root privilege when su is used